# In Xcode 5 (ios7) How can i test if an integer or a string was entered in a UITextField?

Tags: ios, nsstring, uitextfield

In Xcode 5 (ios7) How can i test if an integer or a string was entered in a UITextField? For example; 
If the user enters "2.34", this would be a valid entry, 
but if the user enters "." with no numbers, or any amount of decimals together "...." which would be a string, then the user will get an invalid entry UIAlertView. 
In this case i'm using the the numeric keyboard with punctuation, so the period/decimal is the only non-numeric choice the user has. 
Thanks!

Comment: What have you thought about / tried?

Comment: Thank Wain! As soon as i get a chance i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure whether you want to really test that in **Xcode.** I'd rather think that you want to test it in **your iOS application.** If the latter is the case, then use `strtod()`, which is a standard C function that examines if a string represents a valid floating-point number according to C's notation:

```
const char *s = someTextField.text.UTF8String;
const char *end = s + strlen(s); // _not_ someTextField.text.length because of
                                 // subtleties of Unicode encodings...

char *pEnd;

errno = 0;
double result = strtod(s, &pEnd);

if (end == pEnd && errno == 0) {
    // input was valid, `result` is the result of the conversion
} else {
    // there was an error, either an invalid string was entered,
    // or a conversion resulted in an over- or underflow.
}
```

Comment: You should probably use ASCII encoding, because strtod is specified for that!